# Redis Commander - command to show last key

Tags: redis

I'm doing some diagnostics on a system (I didn't develop), and it's running Redis and Bull to queue API calls. I need to see if/why some API calls are failing. I have access to a web interface of Redis Commander.

There's 90,000+ keys, and when you expand the "tree", it takes several minutes to load.

**I would just like a command to run that shows me the last 10 keys added.**

(or a command that tells me the ID # of the last key, and another command that let's me display the data of the key, without needing to expand the tree)

I'm guessing this is really simple, I'm just inexperienced with Redis.

[image: redis commander]

Answer (score 1):

[MONITOR](https://redis.io/commands/MONITOR) is a debugging command that streams back every command processed by the Redis server. It can help in understanding what is happening to the database. This command can both be used via redis-cli and via telnet.

Comment: Unfortunately I get "ERROR: Command monitor not supported via web cli" when I try MONITOR. (And I'd prefer not to SSH if I didn't have to.)